# Changing a list of arrays to 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am new to programming in Python. I was trying to use the `sorted` command to arrange my 2D array from a csv file in ascending order of the first column elements. However, instead of outputting a 2D array, it gives me a list of arrays instead. Here is an example of the problem  I faced.

```
not_ordered_array = [[-0.633,  0.03279], [-7.330e-01,  3.564e-04], [-0.567  ,  0.06843], [-7.000e-01, -5.551e-17], [-0.667,  0.006772], [-0.533,  0.06808], [-0.633,  0.03279]]

ordered_array = sorted(not_ordered_array, key = lambda x: x[0], reverse = False)

print(ordered_array)

[array([-7.330e-01,  3.564e-04]), array([-7.000e-01, -5.551e-17]), array([-0.667,  0.006772]), array([-0.633,  0.03279]), array([-0.6,  0.05097]), array([-0.567  ,  0.06843]), array([-0.533,  0.06808])]
```

I am trying to use operations on the `ordered_array` after this. How do I get the `ordered_array` in a 2D array instead of a list of arrays?